# A stronger form of Rolle's Theorem in the direction of number of roots of $f'(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, polynomials, conjectures

Today I read an interesting generalization of the Rolle's Theorem for **Polynomials** in $E. 28$ of E. J. Barbeau's book on Polynomials.

It says that if $a, b$ are two **consecutive** zeroes of polynomial $P(x)$ then the number of roots $P'(x)$ (counting multiplicities) in $(a, b)$ is odd in number. I saw the proof and all.

Now, this made me conjecture a similar thing for any differentiable function, given **consecutive roots** exist (roots are countable). ALso, I had to assume that the number of roots of $f'(x)$ in $(a, b)$ is finite in number. Also, I don't know if this makes sense, but I also defined multiplicity of roots for $f(x)$ as if $f(a)=f'(a)= \cdots = f^{(n)}(a)=0$ and $f^{(n+1)} \neq 0$, then I say that multiplicity of $a$ is $n$ and I count it as $n$ roots.

**My conjecture** is that the number of roots of $f'(x)$ (counting orders) stictly between any two consecutive roots of $f$ is odd in number.

Also, I think I have proved it given the assumptions. Because clearly  the extremums of $f(x)$ between $a$ and $b$ are odd in number and any point critical point in $(a, b)$ that is not an extremum will be a root with even multiplicity by nth derivative test which I can prove. So, the conjecture holds.

Now, my main questions are, is there a better form of the above conjecture? Also, are any of my assumptions on the countability and infinitude of roots "unecessary"? Are there any analogous results when the roots of $f'(x)$ are infinitude?

Please throw light. Now my question is not very specific or may its asking for too many things, so any related results or links will also be immensely  appreciated.

Also I am in high school and don't much analysis analysis (i know uptil spivak calculus).

**UPDATE:** Since my conjecture (with the assumptions stated seems true) and we are trying to find and analogous extension of it for the case of infinitely many derivatives, I thought we must try to extend the notion of cardinality of a set with odd number of elements to sets with infinitely many elements.

Here is my **proposed extension:** Call the cardinality of a set $S$ with infinitely many elements, **odd** iff we cannot **cannot** partition $S$ into $A$ and $B$ such that there exists a bijection from $A$ to $B$. When the cardinality is finite, then the above definition is clearly true by definition.

So, does the above extension make sense (even when the set is countable)?

Now with the above definition can we say that the number of roots of $f'(x)$ in $(a, b)$ odd? (at least when the roots are countably infinite?)

Comment: What exactly is your conjecture? By the way, your intuitive definition of "multiplicity" is a common definition.

Comment: @lattice Thanks, I did not know about order of roots. My conjecture is that the number of zeroes (counting orders) of $f'(x)$ between any two cosecutive roots of $f(x)$ is odd in number. I think this is true.

Comment: But I am asking for its extensions or generalistions with lesser assumptions than in my conjecture.

Comment: You also need to assume that all roots have finite multiplicity.  It is quite possible to have a smooth function with a root of infinite multiplicity, i.e. all derivatives of the function are $0$ there.

Comment: I'm sorry, "multiplicity" was indeed the right term, I mixed some things up. Since Rolle's theorem holds for any continous function, your conjecture should also hold for any continous function.

Comment: @But why do I need to assume that? My question is only about roots of $f'(x)$ in $(a, b)$ not at the end points. Sorry, if I did not clearly state that in my question. I did mention it in my proof sketch though and in the analogous result for polynomials.

Comment: @lattice No, you need differentiability as well

Comment: Before I post my solution and to make everything clear let us analyze the original problem, we should remark the following useful comments: If $P$ has to two consecutive zeros  then $P$ has a degree greater than or equal $2$. Consecutive zeros means that there is no $x_0\in(a,b)$ such that $P(x_0)=0$. At the same time if $deg(P)\ge 3$, then $P'(a)=P'(b)=0$, so $P'$ will keep $a$ and $b$ as zeros (and so $a,b$ are extreme values for $P$).  to be continued...

Comment: Therefore, the remaining zeros have three cases : $P'(c_j)=0$, for all $c_j>b$ for all $j=3,4,...,n$ ($n$ is the degree of $P'$) or $c_j<0$ for all $j$ or the zeros lie in two regions $>b$ or $<a$. To generalize such fact for arbitrary $f$, we should note that $f$ must be analytic (or entire) and satisfies the condition you assumed for each zero, so that we can express $f$ as a product of its zeros multiplying with another function $h$ such that $h(x_0)\ne0$ for all zeros of $f$ (fact in complex analysis). Another detailed assumptions must be assumed. I will post a solution as soon as i can.

Comment: You have a problem defining the multiplicity of a zero of $f'$. For example, let $f(0)=0$, and $f(x)=\exp (-1/x^2)$  for real $x\ne 0.$ Then $f(x)$  and all of its derivatives $f^{(n)}(x)$  are $0$ when $x=0$.

Comment: @Cupid umm sorry again. I was just thinking of local extremas, but that also doesn't work if the function is constantly zero on some interval...

Comment: @user254665: The function $\exp(-1/x^2)$ is not real analytic, this function $C^{\infty}$ does not have Taylor series

Comment: @mwomath. Yes. The Q  does not refer to analytic, as distinct from real  $C^{\infty} $ functions.

Answer (score 1):

Define

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1-(x-1)^2, & x\le 1  \\ 
1+(x-1)^2-(x-1)^3, & x>1 . \end{cases}$$

Then $f$ is continuously differentiable on $\mathbb R,$ is strictly increasing on $(-\infty,5/3)$ and strictly decreasing on $(5/3,\infty).$ Thus $f$ has exactly two zeros, one at $0,$ and one somewhere to the right of $5/3.$ We have $f'(1) = 0 =f'(5/3).$ At neither of these zeros of $f'$ do we have $f'' =0:$ $f''(1)$ doesn't exist, and $f''(5/3) = -2.$ So it would appear the zeros of $f'$ are each of order $1.$ Thus between the consecutive zeros of $f$ we have the number of zeros of $f'$ (counting multiplicity) equal to $2.$

If there is an objection because $f''(1)$ fails to exist, fine. But $f$ is continuously differentiable, hence differentiable, hence satisfies the only hypothesis I see on the smoothness of $f.$ So if this example is disallowed, you need to tell us exactly why, i.e, how smooth $f$ is assumed to be.

Comment: Thanks! I think I need the higher derivatives to exist, at least the points where the derivative is zero cause we are counting multiplicities. Actually this is my conjecture, so I don't really know what is exactly required for it to hold. So, first for simplicity lets first assume that the function needs to be infinitely differentiable. Sorry, for being vague about this in my initial post.